# No me permite tomar los datos de un json para usarlos en un componente en React

Tags: json, reactjs

Me arroja el siguiente error:

export 'categories'.'map' (imported as 'categories') was not found in '../../../api/db.json' (possible exports: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Aca debajo dejo las fotos del componente que llama el json, asi como del json mismo. Sin embargo dentro del map pongo un console.log(item) y me devuelve las categorias que se encuentran en el json, no entiendo por que arroja ese error cuando trato de usar los datos en otro componente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo de mi json es este

```
introducir el código aquí
```

Comment: El código debe ir en formato de texto por favor. ;)

Comment: cual es el contenido de db.json?